# How to Insert Values in Specific Excel Cells From DataGridView

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can you please help me to figure out how I can insert DataGridView values into a pre defined excel template (Into Specific Cells)?
I have a DataGridView on my windows Form which is getting the values from user input. Now I would like to enable users to export the DataGridView values into an excel file (A File like attached excel file).
As far as I know I have to create the headers and add them to the code programmatically but for the DataGridView part, honestly I have no idea how I can do that?
As you can see the Form (Box) is starting from B2 to K2 and end from B21 to K21 Now my question is how i can start importing values from B4 - k4 and so on?
Is there any way I can format the style of the cell (like Background color or font style and size) from C#? I mean generating a form like what is looking in attached Excel programmatically.

Thanks for your time in advance

[image]

Comment: Someone's going to say it, so I may as well: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but ff you are using Office Interop, you can insert a 2-dimensional array into a range in Excel.

The following snippet might not be correct (no VS nearby and I haven't used excel automation for a long time) but you'll get the picture.

```
Excel.Range oRange = oSheet.Range("B2",Missing.Value); 
oRange.Resize(myArray.GetLength(0),myArray.GetLength(1)); 
oRange.Value = myArray;
```

Comment: Thanks Koen, bur what I am looking for is just inserting values from an specific cell. is it part of two dimensional array?

Comment: You could create a 2-dim array from the records in your gridview. And with the snippet I've provided you can insert it all at once in the excel-file.